# How to build a recursive dictionary tree from an ordered adjacency list

Tags: python, django, algorithm, recursion, dictionary

I've been trying to figure this out all day and Im at my wits end. Maybe I'm just getting to old for this.

I'm trying to build a tree for the load_bulk feature on django-treebeard as specified [here](https://tabo.pe/projects/django-treebeard/docs/tip/api.html#treebeard.models.Node.load_bulk)

To save you looking, it should look like this:

```
data = [{'data':{'desc':'1'}},
         {'data':{'desc':'2'}, 'children':[
          {'data':{'desc':'21'}},
          {'data':{'desc':'22'}},
          {'data':{'desc':'23'}, 'children':[
            {'data':{'desc':'231'}},
          ]},
          {'data':{'desc':'24'}},
        ]},
        {'data':{'desc':'3'}},
        {'data':{'desc':'4'}, 'children':[
          {'data':{'desc':'41'}},
        ]},
]
```

'data' holds the record, and if it has children, 'children' is a list of more 'data' dicts (that can also contain a list of children and so on recursively)

I get the data as an ordered list (ordered as in depth first, not by id):

e.g:

```
[
    {'id': 232, 'name': 'jon', 'parent': 'None'}
    {'id': 3522, 'name': 'dave', 'parent': '232'}
    {'id': 2277, 'name': 'alice', 'parent': '3522'}
    {'id': 119, 'name': 'gary', 'parent': '232'}
    {'id': 888, 'name': 'gunthe', 'parent': '119'}
    {'id': 750, 'name': 'beavis', 'parent': 'None'}
    {'id': 555, 'name': 'urte', 'parent': '750'}
]
```

How can I transform it into a treebeard compliant dictionary that would look like this (typo's excepted):

```
[
{'data': {'id': 232, 'name': 'jon', 'parent': 'None'},
 'children': [
              {'data': {'id': 3522, 'name': 'dave', 'parent': '232'},
               'children': [
                            {'data': {'id': 2277, 'name': 'alice', 'parent': '3522'}}
                           ]
              }
              {'data': {'id': 119, 'name': 'gary', 'parent': '232'},
               'children': [
                            {'id': 888, 'name': 'gunthe', 'parent': '119'}
                           ]
              }
             ]
{'data': {'id': 750, 'name': 'beavis', 'parent': 'None'},
 'children': [
              {'id': 555, 'name': 'urte', 'parent': '750'}
             ]
}
```

]

I guess I need some kind of recursion function seeing as its a recursive structure but all my attempts have failed. My brain doesnt do recursion so good.

I did a lot of searching and found mostly solutions pertaining to lists or other structures that i cant mould to fit. I'm a relative noob. ps i had more fun manually typing out the example than i did the rest of day (apart from dinner time).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe there are better ways, but here is one solution:

```
users = [
    {
        'id': 232,
        'name': 'jon',
        'parent': None
    },
    {
        'id': 3522,
        'name': 'dave',
        'parent': 232
    },
    {
        'id': 2277,
        'name': 'alice',
        'parent': 3522
    },
    {
        'id': 119,
        'name': 'gary',
        'parent': 232
    },
    {
        'id': 888,
        'name': 'gunthe',
        'parent': 119
    },
    {
        'id': 750,
        'name': 'beavis',
        'parent': None
    },
    {
        'id': 555,
        'name': 'urte',
        'parent': 750
    }
]

users_map = {}
for user in users:
    users_map[user['id']] = user

users_tree = []
for user in users:
    if user['parent'] is None:
        users_tree.append(user)
    else:
        parent = users_map[user['parent']]
        if 'childs' not in parent:
            parent['childs'] = []
        parent['childs'].append(user)

print(users_tree)

#user as {data: user, childs: []}

users_map = {}
for user in users:
    users_map[user['id']] = {'data': user, 'childs': []}

users_tree = []
for user in users:
    if user['parent'] is None:
        users_tree.append(users_map[user['id']])
    else:
        parent = users_map[user['parent']]
        parent['childs'].append(users_map[user['id']])

print(users_tree)
```

Comment: Actually, I think this is quite a good solution. I was trying to think of how to avoid processing the child nodes before a parent has been processed, but your approach to just pre-allocate a new `dict` that uses the `id` field to map to the nodes is very good. I guess if for a large number of nodes space became a huge issue, you could bite the O(n*log(n)) bullet and just sort the list of nodes by the `parent` field first (which will put the `None` parents up front), and then your for-loop will work even without `users_map`. But for most practical cases there's no need to pre-sort like that.

Comment: Thankyou Todor. It's better than I managed but still not quite there.

Comment: Ran out of time on last edit... Thankyou Todor. It's better than I managed but still not quite there. This creates the 'children' as a member of the data row. The specification requires {'data':{datarow..}, 'children': [{listofdicts...}] }.  i.e. 'data' keys datadict and 'children' keys a list of dicts. I would be most delighted if you could try again :)

Comment: @ESM thas for this idea, i will remember that and will definitely try it someday.

Comment: Hey Todo. You're pretty good at this. If I need to hire a programmer I'll be in touch. Its almost perfect except for the fact that it creates an extraneous empty children dict for those unfortunate enough to not have children. This is not included in the specification so I can only give you 9 out of 10 :p  Thanks dude. You're awesome. I'll test it out proper with treebeard tomorrow and see if he's as fussy as me.

Comment: u can move the childs list Initialization in the else statement (the same way how i did it the first time)

    for user in users:
        users_map[user['id']] = {'data': user}

    # another code  

    else:
        parent = users_map[user['parent']];
        if 'childs' not in parent
            parent['childs'] = [];
        parent['childs'].append(users_map[user['id']])

i know u can do this alone :p

Comment: Nice, but what if item could have more than one parent?